# Youtube API not building iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube-api

I am using Youtubes API to embed videos into my site, I followed the simple setup guide and now I am start to customise my player further using the options, everything is working fine until my first video stops playing.

Basically, when a user clicks a thumbnail in one of many sections on the page, an overlay page is loaded via $.get and that builds the video overlay, below is some markup and jquery to aid the problem:

Request video section :

```
<script>
$('.video_overlay').click(function(){

    var appended = false;

    if(appended == false) {
        // Load the video section
        $.get("<?php echo VIEWPATH ?>components/video.php", function(data){
            $('.container-full').append(data);
        });

        appended = true;
    }

    return false;
});
</script>
```

This script requests the video.php view and appends it to the document:

Video.php simply consists of 2 divs (for wrapping) and an inner div with the id of player, upon the API's request completing this is normally replaced by the iframe.

```
<div class="video_wrapper">
   <div class="video">
       <div id="player"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Finally I shall paste the JS which controls the iframe being added:

```
<script>

// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '90%',
        width: '90%',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
//    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
//    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 0) {
        hidePlayer();
    }
}

// Hides the video player and loads the sections back in
function hidePlayer() {
    $('.video_wrapper').animate({
        opacity:0
    }, 500, function(){
        $('.row').animate({
           opacity:1
        }, 500, function(){
            $('.video_wrapper').remove();
        });
    });
}
```

When I detect a video state of 0 (finished), hidePlayer() is called, this animates the player out and then removes the video section from my document.

However if I then click on the same video again, the video.php file is loaded but the iframe is never created, I assume this is because the API code is not downloaded again.    How would I go about fixing this issue?

Regards,
Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make simpe, no need to load a file `video.php`, you lose too much time. Just hide the element and show him when the video is played.
And then you add a `click event` to play the video when you click on the same video !

```
$(".launch_video").click(function() {

    $(".video_wrapper").show();
    player.playVideo();

});
```

**Full code :**

```
    <div class="launch_video"></div>
    <div class="video_wrapper" style="display:none">
       <div class="video">
           <div id="player"></div>
       </div>
    </div>

<script>   
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '90%',
            width: '90%',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
    //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
    //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if(event.data === 0) {
            hidePlayer();
        }
    }

    // Hides the video player and loads the sections back in
    function hidePlayer() {
        $('.video_wrapper').animate({
            opacity:0
        }, 500, function(){
            $('.row').animate({
               opacity:1
            }, 500, function(){
                $('.video_wrapper').remove();
            });
        });
    }


    $(".launch_video").click(function() {

        $(".video_wrapper").show();
        player.playVideo();

    });
</script>
```